# Bayes formula and Movie critic

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

I have the following exercice to solve in order to understand more conditional probabilities.
Consider a movie critic who have the following ratios:

- 95% of the movies I liked are recommended by the critic
- 95% of the movies I disliked are not recommended by the critic
- I like in general 1% of the movies

Now knowing that the critic likes a movie, what is the probability I like it too?

In order to solve the exercice, I supposed that I have 2 variables A & B:

1. A  can take 1 if I like the movie and  if 0 dislike it.
2. B  also takes 1 if the critic likes the movie and 0 if he dislikes it

Using Bayes's formula, I tried to calculate P(A=1\B=1)=P(B=1\A=1)*P(A)/P(B=1)
which is the same as P(A=1\B=1)=P(A=1 & B=1)/P(B=1)

Now we know that P(A=1 & B=1)=0.95. 
The diffculty I am having now is in the calculation of  P(B=1).

Any Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT

Use:

$$P(B) = P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A^C) = P(B|A) \cdot P(A) + P(B|A^C) \cdot P(A^C)$$

Also:

$$P(B|A^C) = 1-P(B^C|A^C)$$

(You're given $P(B|A)$ and $P(B^C|A^C)$, and I am sure you can figure out $P(A^C)$ yourself!)

Comment: How do you know that the statement: " 95% of the movies I liked are recommended by the critic " is equivalent to  P(B=1 | A=1)? it sounds more like P(B=1 & A=1).

Comment: @Med.ali "95% of the movies I liked are recommended by the critic" means that if you point to a movie that I liked, then there is a 95% chance that the critic recommends it. That is: *given* that some movie is one that I liked, there is a 95% that the critic recommends it. So that is a conditional probability: $P(B|A)$.  $P(B \cup A)$ is something different: that is the chance that out of all movies (i.e. unconditionalized) it is true that I like it and the critic recommends it.  ... (part I of II)

Comment: @Med.ali Now notice that I only like 1% of all movies. And, of those, 95% the critic recommends. So, out of all movies, $A$ and $B$ are both true only $0.95$% of the time.  That is, $P(B \cup A) = 0.0095$.  But $P(B|A)=0.95$.  And indeed $P(B \cup A) = P(B|A) \cdot P(A) = 0.95 \cdot 0.01 = 0.0095$ .. (part II of II)